Ubuntu 24.04.1 Desktop ISOs (SNAP, APT)
It is my understanding that the Ubuntu 24.04 Desktop ISO installs all the packages as if installed via snap, and uses snap to automatically upgrade programs/files.  Nevertheless, Canonical still supports installs/upgrades/removals via apt.  I'd most appreciate correction if I am wrong regarding all or part of those above.
Assuming that my understanding is, at least, substantially correct when the time comes for the public release of Ubuntu 24.04.1 (or maybe 24.04.2), is it possible/practical to have two ISOs, perhaps named as follows:
ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64-snap.iso and ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64-apt.iso
The former iso would be configured much as the current one for 24.04, but all programmes/files for apt would be deleted`.  If, after installation, someone wanted apt, it could be installed from the snap repository (or however that facility is named).
The latter iso would have all the material set up as was 20.04 (i.e., Debian packages), and with all snap programs/files omitted.  Again, if, after installation, someone wanted to snap, it could be installed from its Debian package in the repository.
Were this done, would either or both ISOs be small enough to burn onto a DVD? What is the procedure for bringing this proposal to Canonical's attention?

Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ISOs install mostly deb packages, as 24.04 is the deb based system. Ubuntu Core 24 installs snap only systems, so your assumption makes no sense to me.  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS [flavors] released with ISOs that actually allowed a snap free install system (ie. not even snapd got installed; and the snap list command done in QA had the expected result that you can install snapd via apt install snapd; ie. snap command was an expected error!), but those ISOs did include the snapd on ISO as most users (I assume) want the added functionality provided by snap.

Also have you thought through what you're actually considering, Ubuntu Desktop installer (ubuntu-desktop-installer) and Ubuntu Server (subiquity) are both snap packages, thus the snapd system is REQUIRED to be on the ISO.  The flavors allowing the snapd free install used the calamares installer, which is an installer that (I believe) won't be used by Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server into the future for [valid] reasons. Your assumptions are both incorrect & won't work (unless you're talking about flavors that already offer snapd free installs)

FYI:  If you're wanting a small ISO, a quick look at the current smallest 24.04 LTS (daily) ISO is noble-mini-iso-amd64.iso 2024-07-21 10:48 89M or 89 MB in size... that'll fit on one of the mini-CDs if required already !!   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_CD says capacity is 155MB)

@guiverc  "as most users (I assume) want the added functionality provided by snap" at least it's questionable because snaps can take sufficient time to mount/uncompress
